# How do I make a popup screen to appear once I toggle a flipswitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create a school project.

I'm looking to have a toggle button with Yes/No assigned, and when the option is toggled, I would like a corresponding popup to appear to confirm the change.

What would the best way to perform this, because I have tried a couple of variations with no luck. Thanks!

```
<!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <form id="flipswitchTeacher">
            <label for="flipswitch">Are you available to teach?</label>
            <select name="flipswitch" id="flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch" data-corners="false">
                <option a href="#confirmTeacherNo" value="no">NO</option>
                <option a href="#confirmTeacherYes" value="yes">YES</option>
            </select>
        </form>


        <div data-role="popup" id="confirmTeacherNo" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
        <p>Confirm No</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="popup" id="confirmTeacherYes" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
        <p>Confirm Yes</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried that didn't work

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include the jQM libraries. It has been amended.

Comment: @A.M. your example does not appear to include any JavaScript or jQuery script. You will want to create a `change` callback that looks at the value and creates the dialog or popup when the value meets your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the details found here: https://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/ you will see:

> Using the markup-based configuration, when a link with the `data-rel="popup"` is tapped, the corresponding popup container with the id referenced in the href of the link will be shown. To open a popup programmatically, call popup with the open method on the popup container:
>
> `$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" )`

This can be executed like so:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#flipswitch").change(function(e) {
    var target = $("option:selected", this).attr("href");
    $(target).popup("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form id="flipswitchTeacher">
  <label for="flipswitch">Are you available to teach?</label>
  <select name="flipswitch" id="flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch" data-corners="false">
    <option href="#confirmTeacherNo" value="no">NO</option>
    <option href="#confirmTeacherYes" value="yes">YES</option>
  </select>
</form>


<div data-role="popup" id="confirmTeacherNo" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
  <p>Confirm No</p>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="confirmTeacherYes" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
  <p>Confirm Yes</p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.